How to Include only a few Files as a Submodule Instead of the entire project in Visual studio
I have added a submodule to my repository and can work with it as expected when it was added as an existing project. However, when I added just a few files that I really need, I was not able to commit to the submodule as I was before. Is this a limitation of Visual Studio, where I can only add a project from another repository and not just the files I need? If so, is there a solution or workaround for this? Thank you.

You can adjust some settings in Visual Studio Code to better manage submodules.

You can set git.detectSubmodulesLimit to 0 or set git.detectSubmodules to false
This can be done by pressing Ctrl+Shift+P, typing settings, and selecting Preferences: Open Settings (UI) or Preferences: Open User Settings (JSON).

If you’re using the UI editor, search for detect submodules and then either uncheck Detect Submodules or set Detect Submodules Limit to 0.
